# Different vertical spacing for beamer slides

Tags: beamer, columns, vspace

[image]I am preparing some slides with beamer.

The issue is that, it seems the `\frame` command treats things differently. That is, if the subsequent stuff is normal text or itemized environment, spacing is okay. If the subsequent thing is `columns` environment, it shifts the text up differently.

Am I right? What to do to avoid this behaviour?

```
%% document class
\documentclass[mathserif, t]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{
\usetheme{Dresden}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

\mode<handout>{
% tema simples para ser impresso
\usepackage[bar]{beamerthemetree}
% Colocando um fundo cinza quando for gerar transparências para serem impressas
% mais de uma transparência por página
\beamertemplatesolidbackgroundcolor{black!5}
}

\begin{document}
\frame{
\frametitle{Transfer Matrix Method TMM}
\begin{columns}
    \column[t]{0.55\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Assuming a wave equation:
        \begin{equation*}
        \psi_j(x) = A_j \cdot e^{p_j(x)} + B_j \cdot e^{-p_j(x)}
        \end{equation*} 
        \item Having a \emph{continuous} and \emph{smooth} curve requires boundary conditions.
        \item For each \emph{slice} the subsequent $A_{j+1}$, $B_{j+1}$ parameters will be identified by the current $A_{j}$, $B_{j}$ parameters through:
        {\scriptsize
            \begin{equation*}
            \begin{bmatrix}
            A_{j+1} \\
            B_{j+1}
            \end{bmatrix}
            =
            M_j \cdot
            \begin{bmatrix}
            A_{j} \\
            B_{j}
            \end{bmatrix}
            \end{equation*}
        }
    \end{itemize}
    \column[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Concatenating the different slices, one obtains:
    \end{itemize}
    {\scriptsize
        \begin{equation*}
        \begin{bmatrix}
        A_{N-1} \\
        B_{jN-1}
        \end{bmatrix}
        =
        M_{N-1}  \ldots     M_{1} \cdot     M_{0}
        \begin{bmatrix}
        A_{0} \\
        B_{0}
        \end{bmatrix}
        \end{equation*}
    }
\end{columns}
}
\frame{ %The shifted up columns occurs here
 \frametitle{Transfer Matrix Method TMM}
    \begin{columns}
        \column[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \textcolor{unibored}{This leads to tunnelling probability $T_x(E)$ which leads to knowing the current density $J(V)$.} %<- This is shifted up!
        \column[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{figure}[htbp]    
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width= 0.8\textwidth]{}
            \caption{Comparison between WKB and TMM transmission probabilities.}
        \end{figure}
    \end{columns}
    \begin{columns}[t]
        \column[]{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{block}{Benefits}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Ability to simulate multi insulator structure.
                \item Better mathematical accuracy.
            \end{itemize}
        \end{block}
        \column[]{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{block}{Drawbacks}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item More complicated
            \item Contains some try \& error options for into its details.
            \end{itemize}
        \end{block}
    \end{columns}   
}
\end{document}
```

Sorry about the lengthy code you can take out whatever you see unnecessary.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Please add pictures.

Comment: I have recently added the picture and retested the code. It works okay if I replace the picture with text. It shifts down as shown by the red arrows when I add the picture though the picure is cropped right at the upper axis limits (i.e. very small white vertical space added from the picutre which is 541x440 pixels)

Comment: The same problem occurs for `table` environments as well. How do I fix it there?

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the `valign` option (introduced by the `adjustbox` package) and the `\captionof` command from the `caption` package:

[image]

```
%% document class
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{
\usetheme{Dresden}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

\mode<handout>{
% tema simples para ser impresso
\usepackage[bar]{beamerthemetree}
% Colocando um fundo cinza quando for gerar transparências para serem impressas
% mais de uma transparência por página
\beamertemplatesolidbackgroundcolor{black!5}
}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\frame{ %The shifted up columns occurs here
 \frametitle{Transfer Matrix Method TMM}
    \begin{columns}
        \column[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \textcolor{blue}{This leads to tunnelling probability $T_x(E)$ which leads to knowing the current density $J(V)$.} %<- This is shifted up!
        \column[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        %\begin{figure}[htbp]    
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width= 0.8\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image}
            \captionof{figure}{Comparison between WKB and TMM transmission probabilities.}
        %\end{figure}
    \end{columns}
    \begin{columns}[t]
        \column[]{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{block}{Benefits}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Ability to simulate multi insulator structure.
                \item Better mathematical accuracy.
            \end{itemize}
        \end{block}
        \column[]{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{block}{Drawbacks}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item More complicated
            \item Contains some try \& error options for into its details.
            \end{itemize}
        \end{block}
    \end{columns}   
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks and I understand that it’s possible to adjust the vertical spacing using valign.  But from a programming point of view why does this thing happen?